# Upload Report with ejbql Data Adapter in JasperSoft Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, ejbql

I've created a report using JasperSoft Studio, and it works fine using a EJBQL Data Adapter with an EJBQL Query.

But now, I need this report to be called from Jaspersoft Server, but I can't figure out how I can setup the EJBQL Data Adapter in the Server, it is possible?